# Vue router alias priority

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have two routes that I have set up in my routes file like this:

```
{
    path: '/:language?/chain/:entity/',
    alias: '/:language?/:entity/',
    name: 'search',
    component: Search
}
```

Because the `path` route is more specific than the alias I have put it as my main `path`.

This works for something like:

`/de/chain/mcdonalds/`

However for something like this it doesn't work:

`/de/mcdonalds/`

Because my main path is `/:language?/chain/:entity/` it will still insert `chain` into all my `router-link` components. Even though it does not match the exact word.

I want that route to take precedence if it matches though. If I swap them around I will inverse my entire situation.

How can I get both of these routes to work properly?

Comment: Why do you want some `<router-link>`s to have `/chain/` and some to not? Wouldn't it be better to have a consistent URL?

Comment: It would be better, but unfortunately this is not up to me. I don't know why I even asked this question at this point because this seems like one of those situations that is impossible to explain here. Thanks for taking a look anyways.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem fully though. Is your problem that `<router-link to="/de/mcdonalds/">` renders a link with href `/de/chain/mcdonalds/`? Are you saying you want the calculated href to match the path in `to`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, until *dynamic aliases* are supported by `vue-router`, this feature is not possible.

You will likely need to do this in the meantime

```
{
  path: '/:language?/chain/:entity/',
  name: 'search',
  component: Search
},
{
  path: '/:language?/:entity/',
  name: 'search',
  component: Search
}
```

Here is the Github link for feature request: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/1858

Comment: That is unfortunate because that is exactly what I need. Thanks for your answer.